# R: not meaningful as factors

Tags: r

what is best practice to handle this particular problem when it comes up? for example I have created a dataframe:

```
dat<- sqlQuery(con,"select * from mytable")
```

in which my table looks like:

```
ID    RESULT    GROUP
--    ------    -----
1     Y         A
2     N         A
3     N         B
4     Y         B
5     N         A
```

in which ID is an int, Result and Group are both factors.

problem is that when I want to do something like:

```
tapply(dat$RESULT,dat$GROUP,sum)
```

I get complaints about columns being a factor:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,2L,1L,1L, :
sum not meaningful for factors
```

Given that factors are essential for use in things like ggplot, how does everyone else handle this?

Setting stringsAsFactors=FALSE and rerunning gives

```
tapply(dat$RESULT,dat$GROUP,sum)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid "type" (character) or argument
```

so I'm not sure merely setting stringsAsFactors=FALSE is the right approach

Comment: It is not clear what you want to sum.  Is it `sum` of `RESULT=='Y'`?  If that is the case `with(dat, tapply(as.character(RESULT)=='Y', GROUP, FUN=sum))` or use `table`. ie. `table(dat[-1])`

Comment: @akrun - thanks yes this was exactly what I wanted to do. My tapply statement wasn't quite right either so thank you for clarifying. and the as.character takes care of the factors. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to sum up the "Y"s in the RESULT column.

As suggested by @akrun, one possibility is to use `table()`

```
with(dat,table(GROUP,RESULT))
```

If you want to stick with the `tapply()`, you can change the type of the RESULT column to a boolean:

```
dat$RESULT <- dat$RESULT=="Y"
tapply(dat$RESULT,dat$GROUP,sum)
```

If your goal is to have some columns as factors and other as strings, you can convert to factors only selected columns in the result, e.g. with

```
dat<- sqlQuery(con,"select ID,RESULT,GROUP from mytable",as.is=2)
```

As in the `read.table` [man page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) (recalled by the sqlQuery man page) : `as.is` *is either a vector of logicals (values are recycled if necessary), or a vector of numeric or character indices which specify which columns should not be converted to factors.*

But then again, you need either to use `table()` or to turn the result into a boolean.

Comment: thanks @MTk. Yes I have used the table command before, thanks for reminding me. probably easier all round. akrun provided a satisfactory was to do this with tapply() also.

what is interesting is being able to supress factors in the sqlQuery(). good tip I will be using that one a LOT!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what your question is, either.  If you're just trying to sum the Y's, how about:

```
    library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, 
              RESULT = as.factor(c("Y","N","N","Y","N")),
              GROUP = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A")))

df %>% mutate(logRes = (RESULT == "Y")) %>%
       summarise(sum=sum(logRes))
```

Comment: Please note generally it's better to ask to OP to clear question with Comments before to try to answer it. Thank you